# Php not see data from javascript ajax FormData (input type file )

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

When i try send FormData object with ajax php code not see my file.
Array `$_FILES` is empty and `$_POST` too.
But in browser ajax request send this file.

```
<input type="file" name="fileToUpload" id="fileToUpload" value=""

<input id="uploadxml" class="upload-excel button" type="submit" value="Upload Excel File"
          name="button">


$submit.on('click', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    var formData = new FormData();
    var xhr      = new XMLHttpRequest();
    formData.append('file', jQuery('#fileToUpload').prop('files')[0]);

    xhr.open('POST', 'url', true);

    xhr.send(formData);

    xhr.onreadystatechange = function() {
      if(xhr.status !== 200) {
        console.log(xhr.status + ': ' + xhr.statusText);
      } else {
        if(xhr.readyState == 4) {
          console.log(xhr.responseText);
        }
      }
    };
});


<?php
echo $_POST;
echo $_FILES['file'];
?>
```

Comment: Have you watched the AJAX request / response in your browser's console? Did you forget a closing brace on your first input, or is that just a copy/pasta error? How are you populating `$submit`? Why are you switching to VanillaJS when you start the request with jQuery syntax? Where did you get this code from?

Comment: Yes i watched Ajax request 
------WebKitFormBoundaryh24pn8WrfIZtfseH
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="file"; filename="DB-SampleForWritingScript.xlsx"
Content-Type: application/octet-stream


------WebKitFormBoundaryh24pn8WrfIZtfseH--

Comment: Brace is copy/paste error.
It's my code)

Comment: How are you examining the output of the PHP program in order to confirm that they are empty?

Comment: var_dump and xhr.responseText

Comment: Resolved!
Thanks all.

Comment: That's great. How did you resolve it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Php not see data from javascript ajax FormData (input type file )
Resolved